# How to stretch an element out vertically so that it is always at least as tall as its sibling?

Tags: css, height

For some context, what I am trying to accomplish is that I want a sidebar that always stretches to the very bottom of the page. The height of its contents is not fixed, nor is the height of the main content on the page. Therefore, there's basically three different possibilities:

1. Neither the main content, nor the sidebar's contents, are long enough to reach the bottom of the viewport. The sidebar stretches down to reach the bottom anyways.
2. The main content is longer than both the viewport and the sidebar's contents. The sidebar stretches down so that it is as long as the main content.
3. The sidebar content is longer than the viewport and the main content. The page is extended far enough that you can see the entire contents of the sidebar.

If the page is longer than the viewport, there should be only ONE scrollbar and the user will use that to scroll both the main content and the sidebar simultaneously. They cannot scroll separately.

My idea was to give the sidebar the style "min-height:100%". If the sidebar fills 100% of the containing element's height, and the containing element touches the bottom of the page, then the sidebar will stretch to the bottom of the page. min-height means it should be able to expand the size of the page if its own contents happen to surpass that height, too.

You might have already figured out that this doesn't work. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ygLqtogt/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-div">
        <div class="tall-div"></div>
        <div class="at-least-as-tall-div"></div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    html {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    height:100%;
}
.container-div {
    height:100%;
}
.tall-div {
    height:1000px;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.at-least-as-tall-div {
    min-height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

In order to use min-height on my sidebar div, all of its ancestors need to have the style "height:100%;". Before I added this style, the height of my container div was 1000px, which was the height of its tallest child, my main content div. Once I added height:100%; to all of the ancestor elements, the "height" property of the container div was truncated to just the height of the viewport. Therefore, instead of the sidebar div expanding to fill the entirety of the page, it will only fill the viewport. Scroll down and you will see that the sidebar div isn't long enough.

How do I get the sidebar to expand to the size of the main-content div if it's shorter? Is it possible without using Javascript?

If this specific implementation is not possible, I'd like to hear about other potential solutions. I just thought I'd ask a focused question first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one trick using just css:

```
.container-div {
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.tall-div {
    height:1000px;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.at-least-as-tall-div {
    min-height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
    padding-bottom:10000px;
    margin-bottom:-10000px;
}
```

check the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qa5vu04e/

note the container has `overflow:hidden` and the not as tall div has `padding-bottom:10000px; margin-bottom:-10000px;` though I wouldn't be surprised if there's a display:table-cell method that's more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Set height to parent div and overflow:auto to div that should be auto-sized

http://jsfiddle.net/ygLqtogt/1/

```
.container-div {
    height:1000px;
}
.tall-div {
    height:100%;
    ....
}
.at-least-as-tall-div {
    overflow:auto;
    ....
}
```